# tidyrで連番データにデータクリーニング

Tags: r, tidyverse

Rのtidyrでデータクリーニングをしたいと考えています。

データはラベルが付いていないものを読み込んだのでV1~V1998となっており、型はデータフレームで名前はdfです。

```
v1,v2,v3,...,v1998
1,13,23,...,32
2,14,26,...,32
4,14,27,...,38
5,...
...
354,243,543,...,657
```

のようにv1に時間がはいり、V2~はそれぞれの人のデータとなっております。
これを

```
time,data
1,13
2,14
4,14
....
354,243
1,23
2,26
....
```

のように縦に並べたいと考えています。timeにV1の値が入り、dataにV2~の値が入る形です。

```
df %>% tidyr::gather(key =time,value = data,df[,2:1998])
```

などとやってもエラーが出てしまいます。
どう対処すればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

**追記**
tidyrでないパッケージ利用でも構いません。（スピードが実用に耐えられればですが…）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下を試してみてください:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  v1 = 1:5,
  v2 = sample(11:20, 5),
  v3 = sample(21:30, 5),
  v4 = sample(31:40, 5)
)

df %>% 
  gather(key = person, value = data, -v1)
```

`gather()`はwide型データをlong型データに置き換える関数です。keyには「その値(value)がwide型のときどの変数にあったものなのか」を示し，valueはその値を示します。そして残りの引数(...と表現されるもの)には，「valueに流し込む値がある変数」を指定します。

今回の場合，v1が時間で，縦に持っていくのはv2以降の変数ということから，-v1として縦に持っていく変数から除外しています。これにより，v1は残ることとなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。V2:V1998やc(V2:V1998)などでもやったのですがエラーでした。一番いいのはご提案してくださったマイナスを指定する方法ですが他にうまくいく方法はありますでしょうか？（なぜこれらの方法でうまく行かなかったか知りたいです…）

Comment: 私の環境では，私のコードで`-v1`の箇所を`v2:v1998`あるいは`c(v2:v1998)`としても動作します。だた，`df[, 2:1998]`とする場合は動作しません。
これは，変数の指定について，gather「列位置の整数値」で受け付けるからです。ここで変数名(`v2:v4`など)を指定すると，gather内で自動的にその数値へと変換して処理するため，私が書いたような可能としています。
ところが，`df[, 2:1998]`のように指定するとdata.frame(list)が指定されるため，処理できません。

このあたりはtidyrのversionによっては異なるかも知れません(v0.6.1でやってます)